# Superposition in cascade op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, signal-processing, superposition

From the circuit below I want to find the output \$V_1\$. I'd say that I can use superposition theorem by dismissing \$V_\mathrm{i}, V_2, V_3\$ at a time. That way I could find \$V_1^1, V_1^2, V_1^3\$ and then sum them up.

But aren't \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$ dependent sources (they depend recursively on \$V_1\$)? I'm not supposed to dismiss dependent voltage sources in superposition.

Also, would there be a reason for not dismissing \$V_3\$ (and do superposition just for \$V_\mathrm{i}\$ and \$V_2\$)? This was suggested but I don't understand why.

[image]

Comment: This is a 'state filter'. 2 integrators with 3 inputs at the first stage ('summer'). Calculate v1, then replace all voltages.

Comment: You cant use superposition theorem in this as \$V_3\$ is depending on \$V_2\$ and  \$V_2\$ is depending on \$V_1\$. If you use superposition theorem, you have to use all dependent sources in every application which is the same as using the sources all at once.

Comment: The best method is to use function blocks as it is normal in control theory. Replace each opamp and its components (two integrators and one summing block) with a corresponding functional block and apply control theory rules (block diagram reduction) for finding the transfer function. By the way: The shown circuit is a well-known universal filter structure.

Comment: You can't set V1,2,3 to 0, as they are driven by zero impedance amplifier outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to find the value of V1, **DISCONNECT** the outputs V2 & V3 from the op-amps.
V2 drives P2 and V3 drives R2.
And then apply the "superposition" theorem.

[image]